# email signature HTML populating weird meta stuff

Tags: html-email

For the life or me I can't figure this one out.  I have created an email signature for my team.  In the signature I have plain text and two href urls.  One is my corporate website, the other is the company facebook page.

SOMETIMES, when someone sends an email the recipient will see a large section below the signature that populates an image and website description.  Exactly like how when you post a link into facebook, it will grab an image and website description ect. from the site or OG meta data.

I can't reproduce this very reliably. Every time i've seen it it's been in a gmail inbox.  I first thought it was grabbing the og info.  I updated that info on the website but when i saw it happen again it didn't grab the new og meta stuff.  So it must be just grabbing the first image that loads or and the meta description or something.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks so much!

Comment: How is the link enbeded in the email, as a Link or as a copy/pasted link? That could be the problem. Also what mail system you are using and and example of the template you are using?

Comment: So what I did was create an email signature for myself as simple html.  So the website link looks like:  

<a href="http://mywebsite.com">our website</a>

Then other people in the company just copied my signature and pasted it into their gmail client.  I've never seen the problem happen with my emails.  Only on theirs, and it's not every email and not every person.  Gmail doesn't seem to let you paste in raw html, so they had to just copy mine from an email i sent them.

Comment: Here is what I have in the signature:

<p style="font-family:sans-serif;margin-top:25px;"><a href="http://website.com" style="color:#ff7800; text-decoration:none;">www.website.com</a> | <a href="http://facebook.com/website"  style="color:#3b5998; text-decoration:none;">www.facebook.com/website</a></p>

Comment: Think they have to follow this for the Gmail sig to work
http://mydesignpad.com/how-to-install-html-email-signature-for-google-gmail/

Comment: yea that's basically how I installed mine.  I didn't realize there would be a difference between copying it out of an email or copying it out of a browser.  I'll have someone update theirs this way and see if it happens.  Still don't know what actually causes the issue though or why gmail would even try to generate images/descriptions from a signature url.

Comment: Hey, we've started getting this issue too with our email signature. It's a hand coded HTML signature - keep me posted if you solve it, I'll try a few things at my end, but I haven't worked out steps to replicate the issue yet either.

Comment: @LetterAfterZ  Really annoying isn't it?  Hard to replicate too.  The reply from juanvan seemed to solve it completely for me.  Haven't seen it pop up since I applied his method.  Basically, don't let your people copy and paste from your signature.  Send them the html file and have them open it in a browser and select all from there to copy and paste.